# assertion compareTo in java

Tags: java, assert

```
String title ="A";
int year = 2009;
String director = "Zebra";

String title1 ="B";
int year1 = 2010;
String director1 = "Zzz";

VideoObj a = new VideoObj(title,year,director);
VideoObj b = new VideoObj(title2,year,director);

Assert.assertTrue( a.compareTo(b) == -b.compareTo(a) );
```

What does the meaning of - in the `Assert.assertTrue( a.compareTo(b) == -b.compareTo(a) );` statement???

Please can i get an explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The *meaning* of the `-` is negation, plain and simple. I've seen that idiom in numeric comparisons that return a `-1`, `0` or `+1` value, depending on the comparison. Although it would work just as well for those that return a magnitude as well, `-n`, `0`, `+n` (where `n` is identical).

It's simply checking that the `compareTo` operations give you the *opposite* value when you reverse the operands. In other words, it's an assertion that `compareTo` functions as expected (but not necessarily as guaranteed - see below).

If `a < b` and `b < a` (ie, `a` is both less than, *and* greater than `b`), then you have a serious problem that needs fixing :-)

From the [`CompareTo` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.
>
> In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

Based on that, the assertion is not quite right, it should be comparing `Integer.signum (a.compareTo (b))` rather than just `a.compareTo (b)`, unless it has extra knowledge that the implementation of `CompareTo` is guaranteed to return symmetrical (around zero) values.

Answer (score 1):

Assert.assertTrue will raise an exception if the comparison you are passing is false

This line is checking if you are getting consistent values for compareTo.

CompareTo should be symmetrical and you can verify this by changing the order of the operands and multiplying the result by -1

Comment: I understand what you're saying but commutable is the wrong term. In mathemeatics, that means you can change the order but get the same result, like 10+2 of 15*3 and unlike 7-3 or 12/4. CompareTo, if commutable, would not function very well :-) Unfortunately, I can't think of a simple one-word term to describe it, other than maybe symmetrical.

Comment: I am sorry, this got lost in translation, I was meaning something like symmetrical. Any other suggestion on one good word?

Comment: Both Java and mathematics use the word "symmetric" for this (see for example the JavaDoc to `Object#equals(Object)`).

Comment: Equals is symmetric, but compareTo defines a total order which is antisymmetric

Answer (score 1):

As written, the statement doesn't even do what it looks like it's supposed to do...

The line should be

```
Assert.assertTrue(Integer.signum(a.compareTo(b)) == -Integer.signum(b.compareTo(a));
```

and it tests that the ordering is [antisymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation), that is, if `a < b`, then `b > a`, and so on, as an ordering must be by definition.

Comment: You _definitely_ don't need `signum`, the CompareTo docs specify that the sign returned is as if signum was used.

Comment: False.  Second sentence of the docs: "Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer..."

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29

I think this is testing that the `compareTo()` method is implemented properly.

For any implementation of the `Comparable` interface

```
a.compareTo(b) == -b.compareTo(a)
```

should *always* be true. If it wasn't, you would get nonsensical results when performing operations that use compareTo(), such as sorting your objects.

**Update**: OK,OK, only the *sign* needs to be opposite for Comparable to work correctly! - but testing that the values are equals *and* have the opposite sign ensures this - it's just a stricter test than is, er, strictly required.

Comment: The _sign_ should be opposite, yes, but the values themselves need not be negated.  It's totally fine for e.g. `a.compareTo(b)` to return `2` and `b.compareTo(a)` to return -1.

Comment: @Louis, that's not so - see the link provided: "The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y". And why does everyone still link to the Java4 stuff. It's like they're living in the dark ages :-)

Comment: Yes, and sgn refers to the sign.  Just like I said.  ;)  (Also, I just pick out the first Google result, as a rule, which is sometimes old...)

Comment: So, for example, if `a.compareTo(b) == 2`, and `b.compareTo(a) == -1`, then the specification is satisfied: `sgn(a.compareTo(b)) == sgn(2) == 1`, and `sgn(b.compareTo(a)) = sgn(-1) = -1`, which are negatives of each other, as specified.

Comment: @Louis, you misunderstood my comment on two counts. First, the dark ages bit was a subtle jab at DNA rather than yourself :-) Second, the docs state: the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1. That compareTo behaviour you cite in the previous comment is _invalid_ as per the docs.

Comment: Updated the answer to ensure full pedantry. And yes, Java 1.4.2 was the first hit in Google. It's not like they're going to change the meaning of compareTo() between versions... ;-)

Comment: No worries.  Also, for reference, you can find several examples of JDK classes that return values other than 0, 1, and -1: `Character`, for instance.  Assuming that the values are exact negatives is...a risky assumption, and if you write a switch statement on the result of a comparison, without taking the signum first, heaven help you...

Answer (score 0):

It'd be useful to see the implementation of `compareTo`, but basically the assertion is testing that `a <= b` implies that `b >= a` for the defined comparison criteria (not the *literal* `<=` and `>=` operators on numbers). If the comparison fails, it means that the `compareTo` method is not behaving as expected.

With the given information, one possibility is that `VideoObj a` is "less than" `VideoObj b` if `a`'s title is less than `b`'s title under lexicographical ordering.

Answer (score 0):

a.compareTo(b);

this method: 
returns 1 if a>b
returns -1 if b>a
returns 0 if a=b

so it will be change a>b to b>a
and b>a to a>b

> a.compareTo(b) and -b.compareTo(a) are the same.